# Use a google sheets formula to set text value as italic

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'd like to concatenate values in a text cell so that a part of the cell is standard font and a part of it is italic. I'm envisioning something like this:

="("&italic("text sample")&")"

... where the enclosing parentheses are standard font and the text is italic. So the result would look like this: (*text sample*). Obviously, my example is not an actual formula.

Anyone know how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of research, looks like there is no way to do this with native google sheet functions. A custom function would be needed. Not really a big problem, but a function that I wish were there to use.